# how to replace has-details with card component per deprecation 6812

Tags: bixby, bixbystudio

I have some result views that use "has-details" which is now deprecated.

e.g.

```
render {
    if (size(this) > 1) {
      list-of (this) {
        default-sort-order {
          sorting(this.name)
        }
        has-details (true)
        where-each (item) {
          layout-macro (altbrains-compound-card) {
            param (altbrainsdata) {
              expression (item)
            }
          }
        }
      }
```

https://bixbydevelopers.com/dev/docs/dev-guide/release-notes/deprecations.6812

DEPRECATED: `has-details` is deprecated. Consider using `on-click.view-for` in a list card components instead. [deprecation 6812]

What does this mean? Can someone provide an example?

Answer (score 2):

The [Movie Agent Sample Capsule](https://github.com/bixbydevelopers/capsule-sample-movie-agent) in the [Bixby Developers Github repo](https://github.com/bixbydevelopers) is an excellent example for this behavior.

The relevant files are:

- [Movie_Result.view.bxb](https://github.com/bixbydevelopers/capsule-sample-movie-agent/blob/master/resources/base/views/Movie_Result.view.bxb)
- [Movie_Summary.layout.bxb](https://github.com/bixbydevelopers/capsule-sample-movie-agent/blob/master/resources/base/layout-macros/Movie_Summary.layout.bxb)
- [Movie_Details.layout.bxb](https://github.com/bixbydevelopers/capsule-sample-movie-agent/blob/master/resources/base/layout-macros/Movie_Details.layout.bxb)

Here's how it works:

1. User asks for something that results in multiple `Movie`s
2. `Movie_Result` view displays a bunch of movies using the `Movie_Summary` layout macro for each `Movie`
3. User taps one `Movie` which triggers the `on-click` containing `view-for (movie)`
4. This reloads the `Movie_Result` view again since its `match` requirement is met and triggers the `Movie_Details` layout since there is only 1 `Movie` to display.